# Why does documentation sample divide by 2 to calculate inSampleSize for Bitmap loading?

Tags: android, graphics, opengl-es, bitmap

In the Android Training documentation is an [article](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html#load-bitmap) about loading large bitmaps efficiently that discusses calculating an `inSampleSize` to downsample an image when it's loaded.  This is the code sample that's shared.

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

What doesn't quite make sense to me is the use of `halfHeight` and `halfWidth` here.  Let's walk through a real world example so I can show what I mean.

I want to load a user's photo into an OpenGL texture.  I've already queried to find that the `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE` is 4096.  The user selects a photo which is 4320x2432, so I need to scale that down a little.

I make the call to my static helper method provided in the docs:

```
options.inSampleSize = BitmapUtils.calculateInSampleSize(options, maxTextureSize, maxTextureSize);
```

Stepping through this code, `halfHeight` will be 1216 and `halfWidth` will be 2160, and inSampleSize will only be other than 1 if that value divided by inSampleSize is still greater than the requested dimension.

When I run this setup, `inSampleSize` is set to 1, which doesn't scale the image down at all, and OpenGL throws a fit because that is larger than the `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE`.

My question is why do we divide by two here?  I don't care if half of my image fits in the requested dimensions, I want the whole image to fit.  Wouldn't it make more sense to keep bumping `inSampleSize` as long as `(halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight` and `(halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth`?

Answer (score 2):

This was my misunderstanding of the intention of this method.  I thought we were looking for an inSampleSize that would decode a Bitmap to fit **inside** the requested dimensions.  I see now that the method is intended to return a value to decode a Bitmap that would be **as close as possible but not smaller than** the requested size.

Answer (score 1):

Strangely enough, this question answered mine. I was confused by the method:

```
// Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
// height and width larger than the requested height and width.
while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
        && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
    inSampleSize *= 2;
}
```

This wouldn't keep both height and width larger than reqHeight and reqWidth. The loop would end as soon as one of them was less than the relevant value. However, because the method uses halfHeight and halfWeight, it's a little like taking a step backwards after overstepping the mark... or measuring a step ahead, rather...

Anyway, I was thinking about the problem at hand and ended up with the following:

```
boolean condition = (height / 2 / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
        && (width / 2 / inSampleSize) > reqWidth;
for (; condition; inSampleSize *= 2) {
}
```

Is it inappropriate to use a for loop is this way? Maybe it would be clearer to simply use:

```
while ((height / 2 / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
        && (width / 2 / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
    inSampleSize *= 2;
}
```

Anyway, I'll try to answer your actual question a bit better. I think this method is designed for minimising memory usage, not for providing a bitmap with an exact required size. A factor of 2 is quite a large jump when scaling down images; you could end up with a bitmap just over half the size you're looking for and then have to scale up. I'm just learning how to use images and am entirely speculating, but wouldn't that look worse than scaling down an image that's almost double the required size?